# Stored MongoDB JavaScript function to move through all child nodes of specified node

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I use tree structures with child references([tree structure](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/)). Each node has it's ID,reference its childs, its "weight" (positive integer). Can you help me to write an example how to move through all child node's of specified node and agregate(SUM) child's "weight".

How can I move througn tree nodes?

**SOLUTION** . Let child's "weight" be additional_time and solving_time. Then let me show code that I use to fill my Mongo base

```
use TreeMongo;
db.dropDatabase();
use TreeMongo;
db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"main_task", parent:null, solving_time:1, additional_time:100});
    db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"big_task1", parent:"main_task", solving_time:10, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task1.1", parent:"big_task1", solving_time:10, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task1.2", parent:"big_task1", solving_time:20, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task1.3", parent:"big_task1", solving_time:30, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task1.4", parent:"big_task1", solving_time:40, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task1.5", parent:"big_task1", solving_time:50, additional_time:100});
    db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"big_task2", parent:"main_task", solving_time:20, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task2.1", parent:"big_task2", solving_time:10, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task2.2", parent:"big_task2", solving_time:20, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task2.3", parent:"big_task2", solving_time:30, additional_time:100});
        db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"task2.4", parent:"big_task2", solving_time:40, additional_time:100});
    db.categoriesPCO.insert({_id:"big_task3", parent:"main_task", solving_time:30, additional_time:100});
```

Here is code of my stored javascript function that I'm using to get node's weight.

```
db.system.js.save(
                   { _id: "count_task_length",
                     value : function(x) { 
                                              var sum=0;
                                              var stack=[];
                                              var item = db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:x});
                                              sum = item.solving_time;
                                              stack.push(item);
                                              while (stack.length>0)  {      
                                                var currentnode = stack.pop();      
                                                var children = db.categoriesPCO.find({parent:currentnode._id});      
                                                while(true === children.hasNext())  {
                                                    var child = children.next();
                                                    sum = sum + child.solving_time+child.additional_time;
                                                    stack.push(child);
                                                }
                                              }
                                              return sum;   
                                          }
                   }
                 )
```

USE this code to check that its working

```
db.eval( "count_task_length( 'big_task1' )" )
```

For additional information check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521713/Storing-Tree-like-Hierarchy-Structures-With-MongoD) post

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have stored procedures

Comment: I'm writting about javascript functions

Comment: @NDGO - the point is that you can't write that code on the MongoDB server as there are no stored procedures/functions. You'd need to do the tree traversal and aggregation on the client.

Comment: May be I was not correct and now I have a solution. If u are intrested in it check my post

Comment: That won't perform at all...you will get masssacred by the peformance impact that function will have