# Understanding returning types of MongoDB commands in stored mongodb javascript functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Some hours ago I wanted to know how to write a Javascript program that I will import to Mongodb and run It in mongodb shell. Here are my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453274/stored-mongodb-javascript-function-to-move-through-all-child-nodes-of-specified)  with my answer(question + my solution). I've got 1 string which are returning type that is unknown for me (I have not got much experience in mongo and javascript). Help me to understand this strings. Here they are:

Is it an array of children or what?

```
var children = db.categoriesPCO.find({parent:currentnode._id});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a cursor which is not javascript fundamental type, `toArray()` method converts cursor to array.

Comment: Docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find).